# Zero-Euclidean Space

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, differential-geometry

I was reading about $m$-dimensional locally Euclidean space from this [page](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Locally_Euclidean_space#Locally_Euclidean_of_possibly_varying_dimension), where it is defined in the following way.

> A topological space $X$ is termed locally $m$-Euclidean for a nonnegative integer $m$ such that it satisfies the following equivalent conditions:
>
> 1. For any point $x \in X$, there exists an open subset $U \subseteq X$ such that $x \in U$, and $U$ is homeomorphic to the Euclidean space $R^m$.
> 2. ... ...

**My Question**

If $m = 0$ (as $m$ is a nonnegative integer), then in the above definition we get a Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^0$. What is the definition of $\mathbb{R}^0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually $\mathbb{R}^0 := \{0\}$ where $0$ is the identity element of the vector space.

However, notice that if you want a topological space $X$ which is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^0$, then that means that every $x \in X$ has an open neighborhood $U$ s.t. $U \simeq \{0\}$. Since a homeomorphisms is in particular a bijection that means that $\vert U \vert = 1$ and thus $U = \{x\}$. Hence $\{x\}$ is open, and thus every point in $X$ is open, making $X$ a discrete space.